# Touch detection when UITextView inside cells of a UITableview inside cell of another UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My view hierarchy is like the following:

(UITableViewController) -> UITableView A -> (Cell) -> UITableView B -> (Cell) -> UITextView C

The table view B is not scrollable, but user interaction enabled.

The text view C is not scrollable, not editable, but selectable.

In fact, the use case is:

I am using table view A to show the list of a user's newsfeed, and using table view B to show the comments of each news, and using text view C to show the content of each comment, which is a NSAttribtuedString, since I want to make user's name inside the comment clickable.

Now the problem comes. I want to enable the user to tap on a comment to do something. However, there is always a delay when the tap is detected. If you tap too fast, there will be no response.

I have tried to set the delayContentTouches on table view A, but it does not work.

I also know that a text view inside a cell will disable the table view's didSelectCellAtIndexPath delegate callback.

So could anyone tell me how to make the detection of the tap on text view C respond immediately?

Or, for my use case, is there a better implementation?

Answer (score 1):

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer 
   = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
recognizer.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds
recognizer.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Any chance to make it with **Long Press Gesture Recognizer** something like above ?

You just need to describe what you want in handleLongPress method.

Answer (score 0):

That is too complex view, but I think you can check that which the view is being touched via 'hittest' to control specific view you wanted.